# Problem with get_option Wordpress function called in customizable stylesheet

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

I am developing Wordpress theme that I want to be flexible and I want the admins to be able to change the colors of the theme. That's why I decided to use style sheet "style.php" that is generated during run time with the following code:

```
<?php 
    header("Content-type: text/css");
    $options = get_option( "option_group" );
?>

body {
    background-color: <?php echo $options["body-color"]; ?>
}

/* The rest of the css goes here......... */
```

and I included this file in the header section like normal style sheet. The problem is that I get "**Call to undefined function get_option()**" error in this file. I am wondering how can I make it work. In every other file where I call get_option() it works completely normal. I would be glad if you can give me any suggestion or work around.

Have a nice day :)

Comment: After some reading here and there I think that there is some problem with that I am calling the header() function before get_option(). But when I try to call get_option() before header() it detects style.php as MIME/HTML file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the stylesheet is included as a `<link>` tag in header.php, like this...

```
<link href="http://YOURSERVER/wp-content/themes/YOURTHEME/style.php" media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

then the `style.php` script doesn't have access to WordPress unless you load WordPress at the top of the script.  Doing that would be tricky & resource intensive (you'd be loading WP twice for every page load.)

Probably a better, more efficient, way of doing this is to inject the custom styles directly in the `<head>` of the document like this:

```
<head>
...
<style>
body {
     background-color: #CCC;
}
</style>
</head>
```

To do this your theme can use the `wp_head` action hook...

```
add_action("wp_head", "my_print_custom_style");
function my_print_custom_style(){
    //look up the option
    //echo out the <style> tag and css
}
```

EDIT----
I made this more complicated than it needed to be.  Since you're coding a theme rather than a plugin you can output the `<style>` tag directly in `header.php` rather than messing around with the `wp_head` action hook.

Comment: Hi Chris! Thank you for your response. My first idea was to put the CSS in the header but there will be a lot of CSS and I decided to move it in separate file because it might get kinda "messy". Maybe I'll put it in the header for now till I find a better solution.

Comment: No prob. You could also generate `custom.css` whenever the admin updates the option, place it in the theme root, and add it as a stylesheet link under `style.css`